# How do I import a module into my file in VS code while both of them are in the same folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have two files, math_functions.py, and test.py under the same folder. I want to import math_functions into test.py but for some reason when I simply type it like below it won't work. I also tried 'Import Example3.math_functions' or when the Example3 folder had a space like so 'import Example_3.math_functions' it still throws an error. I forgot to show the error message but vs code tells me this 'import "math_functions" could not be resolved'. How can I import math_functions? I am running python 3.8

[image: How to import file within same folder]

Answer (score 0):

Try import the class or method directly

```
from math_functions import my_math_function
```

or if you want to import all of them at once, try

```
from math_functions import *
```

Comment: it will still throw an error saying "import math_functions can not be resolved"

Answer (score 0):

Okay so from what I found out, the code will still actually run and let you import the module regardless, I think this is just a visual studio thing throwing an error like this but this will still work regardless, now im curious as to whether there is anyway to get rid or ignore the error message. Thank you to those who have looked into it and tried to help

Answer (score 0):

To import a file in the same folder, @shiny is right:

```
from math_functions import *
```

Referece: [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

About the warning that has no effect on code execution but wave underline displayed, if you're using pylint, you can add the following settings to your user `settings.json` file (opened with the **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** command `Ctrl+,`):

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi",   
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=W,C"],
```

Other Linter settings and detailed information you can refer to: [linting-python-in-vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).